# How to select specific data from database and put it into a HTML form with update?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

This is my code, i need help

i need to get the data from the database and then put in into the form, after the form i need to be able to change the information put into the form and then be able to update it

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "artiest";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=artiest', $username,$password);
$id = $dbh->lastInsertId();


$name = $dbh->SELECT name FROM artist WHERE ID = $id;
$email = $dbh->SELECT email FROM artist WHERE ID = $id;
$gender = $dbh->SELECT gender FROM artist WHERE ID = $id;
$comment = $dbh->SELECT comment FROM artist WHERE ID = $id;
$website = $dbh->SELECT website FROM artist WHERE ID = $id;

$dbh = null;
?>


<h2>Artiest Wijzigen</h2>

<form method="post" action="add_artist.php">  
 Naam: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">

<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">

<br><br>
Website, artiest: <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">

<br><br>
Extra toevoegingen:<br> <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
<br><br>
Geslacht:
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Vrouw
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Man

 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Veranderen">  
 </form>
```

Comment: That's nice.  So what's your question?

Comment: Btw, all for your SELECTs are throwing you errors. But I'm thinking that's probably pseudo code.

Comment: my question is, and i'm not a pro in php im trying to learn it, how to make this code work, i'm not an expert @PatrickQ

Answer (score 0):

First of all please read how to build and execute queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Then, I would suggest getting all this data within just one query:

"SELECT * FROM artist WHERE ID = :id"